# How to post using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, httpclient

I am able to get a webpage using HttpClinet class as follows :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(@"http://59.185.101.2:10080/jsp/Login.jsp");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The page will render two textboes, namely Username & Password. It will also render many hidden variables.

**I want to post this rendered Html to desired address, but with my own values of username & password. (preserving the rest of the hidden variables)**

**How do I do this ?**

---

PS: THIS IS A CONSOLE APPLICATION POC

Comment: The person who downvoted, care to comment anything?

Comment: It's unclear why your question got downvoted. It looks like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `PostAsync` method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    { 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "john"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "secret"),
    });
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        "http://59.185.101.2:10080/jsp/Login.jsp", 
        content
    );
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

You will have to provide all the necessary input parameters that your server side script requires in the `FormUrlEncodedContent` content instance.

As far as the hidden variables are concerned, you will have to parse the HTML you retrieved from the first call, using an HTML parser such as HTML Agility Pack and include them in the collection for the POST request.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this btw ?

Comment: would restsharp be better than html agility pack for this purpose ?

Comment: `RestSharp` and `HTML Agility Pack` are 2 entirely different libraries doing 2 entirely different things. So you cannot ask whether you can use one instead of the other. `RestSharp` is just an HTTP client that you could use instead of the `HttpClient` class which is built in .NET. `HTML Agility Pack` on the other hand is an HTML parser which allows you to parse and query an HTML document (that you have previously downloaded with an HTTP client such as `RestSharp` or `HttpClient`).